# How to make `help` act the same as `--help` in argparse

Tags: python, alias, argparse

I want the `help` option act the same as `--help`.

**sidenote**: I have created a program with the same command line behavior as svn or hg. I managed to do this with subparsers. However I want to make things consistent. That's why I want `help` to work.

Comment: you mean you want to be able to call `help('mymodule')` or `help(mymodule)` ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `help` would be an argument, options are prefixed by '-' and '--', respectively. Do you mean something like `if 'help' in sys.argv: sys.exit('help ...')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following to create an alias and make `program help` act the same as `program --help`

```
import argparse

def help(args):
    args.parser.print_help()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my program')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
p_help = subparsers.add_parser('help')
p_help.set_defaults(func=help, parser=parser)

args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to define `help` as another subparser. I would naively say that you could then link it to a print_help() function that would copy the output of your standard `--help`, but I wonder if there is a way to call the native help() function.

Comment: So do I. In the meantime, I think there's a fastest way than creating a subparser for each argument (as the --help does).